# How to use ajax in ruby on rails to update a form after a field has been filled out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two models, one is called labor_report and the other is employee, My ruby on rails application deals with creating labor reports for a certain employee. So after the employee enters his employee number in a text field for the labor report, i need ajax to grab the corresponding name and department number from employees and fill in the other textboxes for the labor report that correspond to that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jquery and unobtrusive javascript, you could use jquery's "blur", which triggers an event when you click or tab out of a text field:

```
$("input").blur(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/controller/action",
        data: $(this).val(),
        dataType: "script",
        callback: null
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for observe_field.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field

Comment: `observe_field` is deprecated starting from rails 3.0.0.